TypeScript strict nullable issues with multidimensional arrays
I'm trying to create a function which is passed an array of numbers to use as accessors for a multidimensional array.  Checking
if (
  someArray[accessors[0]] === null ||
  someArray[accessors[0]][accessors[1]] === null
) return;

gives me a null exception saying that someArray[accessors[0]] could be null, disallowing the null check from continuing so I get the same error when trying to access the array past the if.  someArray is nullable at every level (Array<Array<number | null> | null>).
I've tried this in a simpler situation by creating a multidimensional array with a variable someInt = 0 and doing the same thing.  With let someInt = 0, it gives the same error.  With const someInt = 0, it compiles fine.
So you'd figure that changing the function parameter "accessors" to readonly would get rid of the error since it's supposed to be the same as const.  Changed it to readonly and the problem persists.
Am I doing something wrong here, or is there a problem with TypeScript's strict nullable?  For various reasons, disabling strict nullable isn't an option.

A code example rather than the description would help understand the question.

This might be one of the exceptional cases where the equality operator == is preferable to the strict equality operator === because undefined == null is true, but we need to see a [mre] to understand the actual issue.

Please include the full text of the error message as well. "a null exception" limits the possible realm to about 30 different errors, depending on how you've set up the types involved.

Typescript can't really track complex dynamic array accesses for the purposes of narrowing. So if try to narrow someArray[accessors[0]] it won't work.
function foo(
  someArray: Array<Array<number | null> | null>,
  accessors: number[]
) {
  if (someArray[accessors[0]]) {
    const val = someArray[accessors[0]] // (number | null)[] | null
  }
  //...
}


You could use temporary variable for each step, which typescript can track much better:
function foo(
  someArray: Array<Array<number | null> | null>,
  accessors: number[]
) {
  const first = someArray[accessors[0]]
  if (first) {
    const second = first[accessors[1]] // fine
  }
  //...
}

However, that's kind of annoying.

What you probably want here is to just use the optional chaining operator ?. to drill in.
function foo(
  someArray: Array<Array<number | null> | null>,
  accessors: number[]
) {
  if (someArray[accessors[0]]?.[accessors[1]] === null) return; // fine
  //...
}

See playground

Need that value later on? Then store in a constant and check it's value to get the narrowing you need:
function foo(
  someArray: Array<Array<number | null> | null>,
  accessors: number[]
) {
  const someNumber = someArray[accessors[0]]?.[accessors[1]]
  if (someNumber == null) return;
  console.log(someNumber)
  //          ^ number
}

See Playground

Ok, thanks, that does work for the if statement, but when I try to use the values of someArray[accessors[whatever]] past the if statement then it doesn't "count" as me having checked nulls and still throws an error about possible nulls.  Specifically I'm doing something like let someNumber = someArray[accessors[0]][accessors[1]] after the if check.  I guess I could use your first strategy to declare each sub-array a const local variable unless you can suggest a better way.

Then do const someNumber = someArray[accessors[0]]?.[accessors[1]] and check that. https://tsplay.dev/weA6Vw. You shouldn't be repeating such complicated array indexing anyways. See my edit.
